# Click webelement until hidden

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application where I press submit button until data available on the table.When in my no data are available then submit button hidden.So we can get logic until submitting button hides we will click.And when button, not available we show on success message and load next browser Url.

```
for (k=0;k>30;k++) {
    try {
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input")).click();
       driver.switchTo().alert();
       driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
       Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
       System.out.println(""+location+"  Done");
    }
}
```

Here  `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input")).click();` this line click my submit button.And after submit one browser alert shows thats why i accept this. In this loop  `for (k=0;k>30;k++)` Blindly i take 30..Is there any logic or any sugggestion how can i manage this...
[image]

Comment: How about using a do-while loop to remove the need for '30' counter? In the while loop check using the falseness of ExpectedCondition.invisibilityOf(btn) ( ! ExpectedCondition.invisibilityOf) as the boolean flag to get out of the loop when the button is invisible. Remove the thread.sleep and use the wait time in the expectedcondition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use existence of the element in a way something like this:-

```
By by = By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input");
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElement(by);

while(buttons !=null && !buttons.isEmpty()) {
    WebElement yourButton = buttons.get(0); // assuming only and the first element in the list
    yourButton.click();
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); // ideally this should be sufficient
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    buttons = driver.findElement(by);
}
```

Comment: I added one picture you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you.

```
 try {
      while(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input")).isDisplayed()){
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input")).click();
       driver.switchTo().alert();
       driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
       Thread.sleep(20000);
     }
    }
    catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
       System.out.println(""+location+"  Done");
    }
```

another solution with findElements,

```
      while(driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input")).size()>0)
      {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input")).click();
            driver.switchTo().alert();
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        }
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
            System.out.println(""+location+"  Done");
        }
 }
```

Comment: I added one picture you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Simply checked with `isDisplayed()` to check whether element is displayed or not

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input"));
//check element is present or not
try {
if(ele.size()>0){
   if(ele.isDisplayed()){
   ele.click();
   }
   }
   //switch to alert and perform operation 
   driver.switchTo().alert();
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
   Thread.sleep(20000);
} 
 catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println(""+location+"  Done");
}
```

Comment: When no button not avilable then it shows
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='content']/input"}

Comment: Thanks but here it will click only one time I want to click the button until disappeared.

Comment: Thanks my answer helps you. Then I guess than you have to use explicit ot implicit wait, or try it with loop. Put this code in loop and try

Comment: @zsbappa are u try

Comment: tried but getting error on this line if(ele.size()>0) problem is in size

Comment: Can u share the URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155295/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-zsbappa).

Comment: I Dont get that alert in HTML

Comment: Ok lt me try it

Comment: Its quite difficult to make ur scenario dear as i Don't get the link. Sorry:) . Please upvote if my answer helps u, your question is nice

Answer (score 0):

Implement below Logic :

```
public void test()  throws InterruptedException 

{
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input"));
    while(checkButton(button))
    {
        button.click();
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }


}               
    public static boolean checkButton(WebElement element)
    {
        if(element.isDisplayed())
        return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

It will click until your element get invisible once it your can perform your action further. Hope this will help.

Comment: Actually, I load URL from excel file so i have to do everything within a loop

Comment: // Create a loop to print cell values in a row

            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {

                // Print Excel data in console

                String location = (row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue() + " ");
                WebDriver driver;
                
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.get(location);


//We need to write code here
            }

                }

Comment: You can use same logic there itself no matter from where you are reading data.

Answer (score 0):

Following way I solve my Problem..Hope Its will help to next visitor

```
 do
   {
   try {

   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@name='yt1']")).click();
   driver.switchTo().alert();
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
   Thread.sleep(20000);
   driver.switchTo().alert();
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   driver.navigate().refresh();

   }
   catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
   System.out.println(""+location+"  Done");
    }
    }
     while ((driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='google_data_save']")).size()>0));
```